# Where is the changelog for the Google Play Billing Library?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I see there is an update in the android SDK to rev. 5, but I am curious what has changed.
Bug fixes? Feature enhancements?

I can't seem to find the changelog anywhere and appreciate your help.
thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just seen that someone has received this email from Google.

> Hello, If you previously used the In-app billing sample code to build
>   your in-app billing system, please use the recently-updated sample
>   code as it addresses an exploitable flaw we recently discovered (note
>   that this only affects the helper sample code; the core system and
>   in-app billing service itself was not affected).
>
> The affected applications are those that use the in-app billing sample
>   library (specifically, the IabHelper and the Security classes in the
>   util directory of the in-app billing V3 sample) and do not perform
>   server-side verification.
>
> An update to the sample and library that fixes this vulnerability is
>   now available at code.google.com/p/marketbilling and also through the
>   Android SDK Manager.
>
> To apply the security update:
>   1. Download the updated source code for the in-app billing sample and library from the Android SDK Manager, which is part of the Android
>   SDK. The in-app billing package is located under Extras -> Google Play
>   Billing Library. **Make sure to update to Revision 5**. (or,
>   alternatively, download the updated source code from the public
>   repository at code.google.com/p/marketbilling).
>
> 1. Merge the new code for IabHelper.java and Security.java into your application, replacing the existing code.
>
> If you prefer to apply the code changes manually, you can browse the
>   diff at
>
> https://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/source/detail?r=7bc191a004483a1034b758e1df0bda062088d840
>
> and merge the modifications into the appropriate parts of your code.
>
> Thank you for your continued support of Google Play.
>
> Regards,
>
> The Google Play Team
>
> ©2013 Google Inc. 1600 Amphitheatre Parkway Mountain View, CA 94043

Seems like an important security update which i would have never heard about, hadent i been curios about the changelog.
I've only found this though, no actual changelog which would still be interesting!

**EDIT:**
OK, from the changelog in the repository they where apparently just "Fixing a couple of bugs."
[marketbilling_changelog](http://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/source/detail?r=7bc191a004483a1034b758e1df0bda062088d840).
The ones explained in the email!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's part of the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/versions.html), which also contains implementation guidelines for version 2 and version 3.